# What is this functions Phase crossover frequency?

Tags: control, control-system, bode-plot, phase-margin, nyquist-plot

OLTF loop gain

[image]

My approach

[image]

[image]

What I have done wrong?

Comment: see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/449847/152903

Comment: @SolarMike What the link you referred to goes to an unanswered question. Plz tell above answer

Comment: The 2nd order TF phase angle in your question is never < -180 deg.

Comment: @Chu so what should be its phase crossover frequency

Comment: Have you considered that the answer might be in the comment to that linked question?

Comment: It doesn't cross the -180 degree line, so it's not defined for this TF. There is no phase crossover. The closed loop cannot be unstable.

Comment: @SolarMike yeas comment is about gain crossover frequency and not about phase cross over frequency

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA As Chu said the phase never crosses -180 degree for this Transfer Function. You can also see it by plotting in MATLAB. Is there anything else you want to ask?

Comment: @sarthakbut if we calculate phase crossover frequency using phase=180 then phase crossover frequency comes out to be 0 .So, what should be correct value for phase crossover frequency doesnot exist or 0.